# visual studio find in files - how to search in office documents? (e.g. docx)

Tags: visual-studio

we want to add docx files to our visual studio solution.
How can we achieve that visual studio "find in files" recognizes the content in office documents? (e.g. docx)

Visual studio 2013 does not search docx or doc file formats, at least it isn't able to do so.

Is there an extension that searches office file types?
Or is there a different way to add our documentation with pretty formatted text to a VS solution? We want to use versioning and "find in files" for our documentation.

Best regards
Oliver

Answer (score -1):

Right click the project and select "ADD" and then "Existing Item". THere, on the right side, you will find a drop down where you can select all files. That way you can get any file to the solution.

Comment: Yes, if course I can add what I want. But "find in files" DOESN'T FIND ANYTHING inside docx, doc, rtf. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I see what your point is now. Since docx used different markup, it cannot be read with the text editor. VS is merely a text editor and cannot read docx however if you save your file to doc and open it from within the visual studio, you can search them from find all reference. BTW, i tried with doc and csv file extensions and they both worked for me. But unfortunately VS cannot still read docx files yet.

Comment: Sorry if i couldnt help. The formatting part of the docx(which is the nice part) is something visual studio text editor cannot read.